# Does visibility hidden DOM listens to JS Events?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

When we set a DOM element to visibility hidden, then does it listen to JS events viz., `click` , `hover` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they keep listening for events but when visible is false we can't make click call or any other mouse event (on user request). Because we cant click on un-visible object..

You can call for example trigger (usually in JQ) click() from your code and this will work but only when you don't have (in click) functions like  getUserMedia or similar. Security call's comes only with user actions.

Best practice when you no need more event listener is to use removeEventListener. After removeEventListener theres no attached event.

Answer (score -1):

If your element is `display: none` it is still part of the DOM. It just isn't rendered in the viewport.

If the elements are set to `visibility: hidden`, the events are not fired.